extract allOf validation from json schema
I have the following json schema that I want to use to validate data. It works well when using jsonschema to validate the basic information and conditional scenarios.
But I have a specific problem where I cannot easily assess whether data is present but shouldnt be, based on the allOf conditions. Its possible to write something custom for simple conditions in python, but where conditions are more complex it may be tricky to scale. Does anyone have any hints or know of any tooling that could help. Many thanks
example schema
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "colours": {
            "type": "integer",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "title": "red",
                    "const": 1
                },
                {
                    "title": "yellow",
                    "const": 2
                },
                {
                    "title": "blue",
                    "const": 3
                },
                {
                    "title": "yellow (variant)",
                    "const": 19
                }
            ]
        },
        "years": {
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 1,
            "maximum": 10
        },
        "sleep": {
            "type": "integer",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "title": "always",
                    "const": 1
                },
                {
                    "title": "sometimes",
                    "const": 2
                },
                {
                    "title": "rarely",
                    "const": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        "shapes": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "integer",
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "const": 1,
                        "title": "squares"
                    },
                    {
                        "const": 2,
                        "title": "circles"
                    },
                    {
                        "const": 3,
                        "title": "triangles"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "gender": {
            "type": "integer",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "title": "male",
                    "const": 1
                },
                {
                    "title": "female",
                    "const": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "colours",
        "years"
    ],
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "colours": {
                                "const": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "years": {
                                "enum": [
                                    1,
                                    7,
                                    8,
                                    9
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "required": [
                    "shapes"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "shapes": {
                                "anyOf": [
                                    {
                                        "const": 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "const": 3
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "properties": {
                            "colours": {
                                "const": 19
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "required": [
                    "gender"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "years": {
                        "not": {
                            "enum": [
                                1,
                                7,
                                9,
                                8
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "required": [
                    "sleep"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

example data
data_list = [
    {"id": "a", "colours": 1, "years": 9, "sleep": 4, "shapes": [1], "gender": 3}, # valid logic but invalid value for sleep
    {"id": "b", "colours": 1, "years": 6, "shapes": 3, "gender": 3}, # invalid as sleep should not be present, nor should gender since the entry to shape is incorrect, shapes also not array
    {"id": "c", "colours": 1, "years": 9, "sleep": 3}, # invalid as shapes should be present
    {"id": "d", "colours": 1, "years": 1, "sleep": 5}, # invalid as sleep is present but shouldnt be
]

example code
from jsonschema import validate, Draft7Validator, ValidationError

for data in data_list:
    validator = Draft7Validator(schema)
    errors = sorted(validator.iter_errors(data), key=lambda e: e.path)
    if errors:
        print(data.get("id"))
        for error in errors:
            print(f"Schema Error in {list(error.path)}: {error.message}")
            
# not indicating that sleep is not required for id d 


You have a lot of unnecessary syntax used with oneOf or anyOf and your conditional if, then and allOf combinations can be simplified quite a bit.
Secondly, if you have more than one condition to enumerate, it would be better to use enum instead of oneOf>const or anyOf>const
The examples provided have additional failing attributes more than you described in your comments. Some of your conditional logic is conflicting, so the schema is illogical as it stands. If you provide all of the conditions, I can help you figure them out.
take this example of a simplified if, then construct. Let me know if you need further help with the conditional statements.
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "colours": {
                "enum": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                    19
                ]
            },
            "years": {
                "type": "integer",
                "minimum": 1,
                "maximum": 10
            },
            "sleep": {
                "enum": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    5
                ]
            },
            "shapes": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "enum": [
                        2,
                        3
                    ]
                }
            },
            "gender": {
                "enum": [
                    1,
                    2
                ]
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "colours",
            "years"
        ],
        "allOf": [
            {
                "if": {
                    "required": [
                        "colours",
                        "years"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "colours": {
                            "const": 1
                        },
                        "years": {
                            "enum": [
                                7,
                                8,
                                9
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "shapes"
                    ],
                    "not": {
                        "required": [
                            "sleep"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "if": {
                    "required": [
                        "shapes",
                        "colours"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "colours": {
                            "const": 19
                        },
                        "shapes": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "enum": [
                                    1,
                                    3
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "gender"
                    ]
                },
                "else": {
                    "not": {
                        "required": [
                            "gender"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "if": {
                    "required": [
                        "years"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "years": {
                            "not": {
                                "const": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "required": [
                        "sleep"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}


thats amazing, thanks for the advice. I had tried using enum, but then I end  up missing information I would otherwise like to keep (additional information that might be tied to a constant) in which case - if a field is described as a const under properties, in the condition/allOf section, I suppose its not possible to then revert to enum - they would have to be of the same type? I will check the validity of the conditions and update the question.

Enums can be considered constants, it just allows you to enumerate more than one in a list. Enums can be a mix of types. Just be sure you don't set a type keyword to constraint the enum to a specific type. Use my example provided above

This is valid   {"enum": [{}, 1, true, null, [], "1"]}
